# How can I programmatically flush Magento's Cache?

Tags: magento-1.9, cache, script, automation

I'm automating release configurations by bootstrapping Mage in several release scripts.  At the end of the scripts, I need to flush Magento's cache.

Is there a way to flush the cache using one of the `Mage` classes or methods?

Comment: try this: Mage::app()->cleanCache() or Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->flush();

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Please try the following code to flush the cache programatically

```
Mage::app()->cleanCache()
```

or

```
Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->flush();
```

Answer (score 41):

If you really wanted to you could also clean just one or more cache types. This is actually how the admin section does it. Under `Mage_Adminhtml_CacheController::massRefreshAction`

You can see that it loops through all the parameters `types` and calls the following

```
$tags = Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->cleanType($type);
Mage::dispatchEvent('adminhtml_cache_refresh_type', array('type' => $type));
$updatedTypes++;
```

Possible types are as follows:

1. config
2. layout
3. block_html
4. translate
5. collections
6. eav
7. config_api
8. config_api2
9. full_page

And these can be returned by calling `Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->getTypes()`

Comment: Having been faffing about with cache clearing programatically this comment is more useful than the selected answer. As it is important to call the dispatchEvent, my Varnish ESI's were not clearing until I added the dispatchEvent call. (Which will of course allow other modules to fire their code accordingly)

Answer (score 6):

A quick external script to clear all cache:

```
<?php

require_once './app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app('default');
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

try {
    $allTypes = Mage::app()->useCache();
    foreach($allTypes as $type => $value) {
        Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->cleanType($type);
        Mage::dispatchEvent('adminhtml_cache_refresh_type', array('type' => $type));
        echo "{$type} </br>";
    }
    echo 'done';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Our we could use [n98-magerun](http://magerun.net/). Especially since you should never flush the cache during execution of deployment scripts. Also look at the `sys:setup:incremental` subcommand for more controlled execution of the Magento setup scripts.

Comment: Can you provide some additional insight into your statement "Especially since you should never flush the cache during execution of deployment scripts"?

Comment: Magento has a feature that automatically runs upgrades. This is triggered, when the configuration cache has to be rebuilt. Unless you specifically need that feature and carefully code for it, you introduce a parallel process you or your colleagues may not have anticipated.

Answer (score 1):

If you Really need to clear all cache storages means use the following code,

```
Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->flush();
```

Here Flush function calls the default magento cache functionality, If you need more clarifications means refer the following url.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15028159/magento-flush-cache-storage