# how magento cache working?

Tags: magento-1.9

Clean the cache in magento

```
 Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->clean();
```

1 . How the above code will work ? it will remove all the cache or any particular instance or page.
     suppose I will add this code on any block initialization code like below.

```
class Fishpig_Wordpress_Block_Sidebar_Widget_Menu
{
    /**
     * Generate the Menu HTML
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function _beforeToHtml()
    {
        parent::_beforeToHtml();

        Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->clean();
        $menuBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('wordpress/menu')
            ->setMenuId($this->getNavMenu())
            ->includeWrapper(true);

        $this->setMenuBlock($menuBlock)
            ->setMenuHtml($menuBlock->toHtml())
            ->setTitle($menuBlock->getTitle());

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will clear *all* the cache types, the same as if you'd checked all the cache types under "Cache Management" - see [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/21299/how-can-i-programmatically-flush-magentos-cache) for details.

If you put that into your block initialization code, you'll be clearing your cache every time Magento runs that code... might not be ideal!